# Angular 8 Ionic image rotation to 90 degrees with typescript code

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to do a image rotation in angular ionic. Also gone through various browser like to install animation, image cropper but it throws various errors. Please suggest a correct process to do rotation for an image with typescript code and it should be angular 8 compatible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do it in CSS to avoid any struggle with Typescript or Angular.

To setup the appropriate CSS-Class you can have a look here: https://code-boxx.com/rotate-spin-image-html-css/

I checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes and it should work when your App runs on a physical Device.

If you plan to manage the start/stop of the Animation i would suggest you use ngClass Directive (Examples: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/angular-ngclass-example/ API Docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

If you really want to do it in Angular, i would suggest you use https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-animation-callbacks-and-key-frames-2d415d657b9d

Or have a Look at https://angular.io/api/animations/keyframes